# Variables with same name in JS outside try scope

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
let tasks;

try {
    await checkMongoConnection();
    const tasks = await Task
        .find()

    await disconnectMongo();

    if (!tasks) { return reject(); }
    // Is is possible to use the same naming?
    tasks = tasks;
} catch(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}
```

In JS is it possible to use the same naming like this? e.g. `tasks = tasks` and set the variable outside the `try` block or do I have to use a new name e.g. `tasks = fetchedTasks`?

Comment: No, use a different name.

Comment: Why are you defining a new variable in the first place ?

Comment: what's `return reject();`?

Comment: As a side note, please try to avoid the [promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1541563).

Comment: If the `reject()` in the code above is from a promise executor (`new Promise((resolve, reject) => ...`), you might want to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). You almost never need or want to use `new Promise` in an `async` function or when dealing with something that gives you a promise (like `Task.find()` apparently does).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts fairly new to JS as you probably gathered. I set the variable like that to avoid try blocks within try blocks..

Comment: Thanks for these comments. I'm rethinking my async approach.

Comment: it is because of [lexical scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in short: JavaScript can look outside for variables and names, however can never look in for values/variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't access the `tasks` variable in the outer scope from the inner scope if you have a `tasks` variable in the inner scope. You can assign to an outer scope variable, but not when it's shadowed by an inner scope variable with the same name.

In the example, you don't need the outer `tasks` so I would just remove it (and the `tasks = tasks` statement). Or if you need it for some reason, remove the inner `tasks` declaration (just remove `const` from in front of it) so the code in the `try` block assigns to the outer `tasks`.

Comment: It's an anti pattern setting an outside variable like that? The reason I do it is because I have multiple try blocks and it would be spaghetti hell if I put try blocks within try blocks...

Comment: @Kex - No, Patrick was referring to the `reject()` in the code and assuming it comes from `new Promise`, see the (new) comments on the question. That said, assigning to an outer scope variable from an inner scope is often less than ideal -- but other times it's fine, so... :-)

Comment: @Kex sounds like you're already violating the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) then. Put each independent piece of logic in a separate async function and just await its call. Doing that should allow you to avoid writing nested `try` blocks.

Comment: What if you have an async function that fails and catch is triggered with the error. In that error block I want to write the message to the database which requires another async call, so I'd have to do another try and catch for that in the catch block. That's my main issue. @PatrickRoberts

Comment: @Kex - It's just like with synchronous functions: Ideally, you don't have a `try`/`catch` at all except at the outermost (or at least *an* outer) layer that handles all of the errors from the nested calls within it. That way, other than a coordinating function, the functions just do what they do (or fail, and the error propagates). In an `async` function, promise rejections are exceptions (and exceptions are promise rejections). One of the big strengths of `async` functions over synchronous functions returning promises explicitly is that rejections propagate up the call tree. :-)

Comment: If you *do* need to write to the database from within a `catch` block, that's fine, but make sure that code in the `catch` block doesn't throw (reject) and hide the original error (which is, again, just like a synchronous function).

Comment: I get what you're saying. I could use a single error catch, identity the error in the catch block and then handle it appropriately. But at some point I need to make an async call to the database to log the error. Would calling a function in the error block `handleError(error)` that does the async database write be an antipattern?

Comment: @Kex - Not in *my* view, FWIW, provided any errors it raises don't shadow the error you're reporting. :-) Since an error reporting an error isn't usually one you want to propagate, you might have `handleError` ensure that it never rejects its promise / throws an error. Use `await` if it returns a promise and you want the `async` function you're calling it from to wait until it completes, or don't if you're fine with the error report running in parallel (ish) with whatever's next.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the discussion. Really appreciate it.